# How to make Async adapter calls within adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Adapter Mashup - IBM MFP 8
I have a common adapter which call other streams to get info. I need to send the consolidate result back to client side.

Ex: I have 4 API call, 1 (2Sec), 2 (2Sec), 3(3Sec), 4(2Sec) 
Total time taken for the adapter is 9Sec instead of max as 3Sec. Calls are triggering sequentially instead of Parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of adapter mashup, the calls are synchronous and sequential. This is by design.

You can submit a Request for Enhancement for this [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=changeRequestLanding&BRAND_ID=90&PROD_ID=702&x=21&y=20).